# Gracefully terminating a Scala program after using Actor.self

Tags: scala, actor

Using *scala.actors.Actor.self* creates a *ForkJoinScheduler*, which sticks around and keeps the program from terminating normally.  I'd like to use Scala actors within a program that is written in Java, and currently uses a thread pool which shuts down gracefully.  It would be ideal if I could coerce *Actor* to use a *DaemonScheduler*, but if need be I'd be happy to issue an explicit termination command.

Here's some sample code:

```
object EchoActor extends DaemonActor {
  def act() {
    loop {
      react {
        case (x: Any, respondTo: Actor) => {
          println("echoActor Got message " + x)
          respondTo ! "Echoing: " + x
        }
        case msg => println("Can't handle message " + msg)
      }
    }
  }
}

object TestRunner extends App {
  EchoActor.start()
  for (n <- 1 to 3) {
    EchoActor !("Time to echo", self)
    println(self.receiveWithin(1000) { case x => x})
    Actor.clearSelf()   //   <<-- This doesn't allow for graceful shutdown
  }
  Actor.resetProxy()    //   <<-- Neither does this
  println("Done.")
}
```

This program doesn't terminate, even though there are no threads left that could use *Actor.self*.  I've tried calling *Actor.exit()*, which just throws an *InterruptedException*, and I'm just about to give up completely on *Actor.self*.  Am I missing something?

**Update**

Just discovered:

```
scala.actorsScheduler.shutdown()
```

which works for global termination, and will get the job done for now.  I would prefer to change the default scheduler to be a *DaemonScheduler*, so please post an answer if you know how.

Answer (score 0):

What self gives you is an `ActorProxy`. An `ActorProxy` has an empty `receive` and the `exit` method you already mentioned. Everything else is inherited from `Actor`. I think the only way to shut it down is by calling `exit` and catching the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Send a message to the actor to exit, eg "exit" or the companion object Exit.  In the partial function which reacts to messages, ie the react block, call the exit() method.  Works fine for me and my application closes gracefully.